# Download youtube videos through cache

Tags: downloading, youtube, cache

After watching a youtube video can I use the cache to download the video on my sd card? Something similar to it is in Windows where after watching a video, an application searches through the cache files to download the video. If yes, then how, or using which app (on Android)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to cache YouTube videos after playing them?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9709/is-there-a-way-to-cache-youtube-videos-after-playing-them)

Comment: Google doesn't seem to like that (most apps which supported that have been banned from GPlay). But you might wish to take a look at my list of [Video-Downloaders](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=93) (also lists some sources other than GPlay, exactly for that reason).

Comment: @DanHulme Caching is different from downloading (saving) an already loaded video, which is what the OP is attempting, as far as I understand.

Comment: @onik I understand what caching is, but I also see that people do not always use the term consistently. Both questions are about saving an already-watched video to the SD card so it can be watched again later.